# How to print the bitmap on two pages?

Tags: c#

i am using the bitmap method to print the DataGridView. 
How to split the bitmap on two pages if the this.dgvTheory.Height is bigger than 500?Everything should stay on the first page,except the bitmap which can go on second page if it's big.

Edited: The rest of the image should go on the 2nd page.

Thanks in advance.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int height = dgvTheory.Height;
    dgvHistTheoCust.Height = dgvTheory.RowCount * dgvTheory.RowTemplate.Height;
    bitmap = new Bitmap(960, this.dgvTheory.Height);
    dgvTheory.DrawToBitmap(bitmap, new Rectangle(0, 0, 960, this.dgvTheory.Height));
    dgvTheory.Height = height;
    printPreviewDialog1.Document = printDocument1;
    printPreviewDialog1.ShowDialog();
}

   private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        this.printDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = true;
        using (Font fnt1 = new Font("Segoe UI", 12f, FontStyle.Regular))
        {
            using (Font fnt2 = new Font("Arial", 13f, FontStyle.Bold))
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawString("just a text", fnt2, Brushes.Black, new RectangleF(new PointF(500f, 10f), new SizeF(300f, 20f)));
                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, 50, 5, 1000, 30);
                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, 50, 35, 1000, 30);
                e.Graphics.DrawString("just a test", fnt2, Brushes.Black, new RectangleF(new PointF(280f, 40f), new SizeF(700f, 20f)));
                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, 50, 70, 300, 20);
                e.Graphics.DrawString("some data :", fnt1, Brushes.Black, new RectangleF(new PointF(55f, 70f), new SizeF(500f, 20f)));
                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, 50, 90, 300, 20);
                e.Graphics.DrawString("some data :", fnt1, Brushes.Black, new RectangleF(new PointF(55f, 90f), new SizeF(300f, 20f)));
                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, 350, 70, 700, 20);
                e.Graphics.DrawString("str", fnt1, Brushes.Black, new RectangleF(new PointF(600f, 70f), new SizeF(300f, 20f)));
                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, 350, 90, 700, 20);
                e.Graphics.DrawString("str", fnt1, Brushes.Black, new RectangleF(new PointF(600f, 90f), new SizeF(300f, 20f)));
                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, 50, 110, 300, 20);
                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, 350, 110, 700, 20);
                e.Graphics.DrawString("some data :", fnt1, Brushes.Black, new RectangleF(new PointF(55, 110), new SizeF(300f, 20f)));
                e.Graphics.DrawString("str", fnt1, Brushes.Black, new RectangleF(new PointF(600, 110), new SizeF(300f, 20f)));
                e.Graphics.DrawImage(bitmap, 50, 135);
                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, 50, 640, 300, 20);
                e.Graphics.DrawString("some data :", fnt1, Brushes.Black, new RectangleF(new PointF(50, 640), new SizeF(300f, 20f)));
                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, 350, 640, 700, 20);
                e.Graphics.DrawString("int", fnt1, Brushes.Black, new RectangleF(new PointF(700, 640), new SizeF(300f, 20f)));
                e.Graphics.DrawString("some data....", fnt1, Brushes.Black, new RectangleF(new PointF(50, 660), new SizeF(1000f, 70f)));
                e.Graphics.DrawString("my sign goes here", fnt1, Brushes.Black, new RectangleF(new PointF(650, 730), new SizeF(300f, 20f)));                   
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Printing on multiple page is controlled by two indicators:

- the internal flag `e.HasMorePages` tells the system to re-enter the `PrintPage` method once more after you return from it.
- some external flag **you** need to set up tells you which page and/or which content you are supposed to print next.

The internal flag is rather simple but you need to know that it wil be **reset** whenever you enter the method!

Your external flag can be anything you want, a bool or a number or it can even be implicit, like the state of a queue.

In your case a simple `bool` will be enough, but for more complex print jobs one may want e.g. an index into a list of items to print..

Let's call your flag `printImageOnPageTwo`. Declare it at class level:

```
bool printImageOnPageTwo = false;
```

Now you can check for it to know if you should enter the part that prints page one or skip it and print the image to the top of page two..:

```
private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender,
                                      System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
   this.printDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = true;

   if (!printImageOnPageTwo )
    using (Font fnt1 = new Font("Segoe UI", 12f, FontStyle.Regular))
    using (Font fnt2 = new Font("Arial", 13f, FontStyle.Bold))
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawString("just a text", fnt2,.....);
        ...
        ...

        if (dgvTheory.Height <= than 500)
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(...., y_InTheMiddle)
        else
        {
           printImageOnPageTwo = true:   // set our flag
           e.HasMorePages = true;        // set the system flag
           return;                       // quit the routine
        }
    }  // end if !printImageOnPageTwo 
    else  e.Graphics.DrawImage(...., y_AtTheTop);
    printImageOnPageTwo = false;         // reset our flag
}
```

Comment: Hello @TaW, that method works very well and i thank you very much.Is it possible to print the rest of the image on the second page?If the image has height 800,print 500 on the first and the rest 300 on the second.

Comment: Sure. You need to change the logic a little and not just set a flag but calculate how many pixels you want to spill to the second page. Then draw on both pages. For the DrawImage calls you need to use an overload with __two__ rectangles where the 1st sourceRectangle has e.g. top=0 and height=500 and the 2nd scrRect has top=500 and height=300. ...

Comment: ...Do look up the various DrawImage overloads!! It is __very__ useful to know [them all](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.drawimage%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), not just to extract portions but also to scale or distrort them and also to place them!

Comment: I marked your answer as solution.Thank you very much,fixed.